# storing elements of an Array in local variables to be used later

Tags: java, variables, split

I am using Java to split a search query on it's spaces

example:

```
String[] queryParams = queryString.split(" ");
```

so search for "New York Yankees" will get put into an array of three elements.

Now, I want to iterate over each of those elements (regardless of the length of the query) and store them in their respective variables so I can dynamically populate another part of my program.

Thanks

Comment: Could you clarify what you want to do? It seems from the question like you don't know how big the array will be in advance, but you say you want to "store them in their respective variables" which makes it sound like you have variables to store them in. What's wrong with just storing them in the array?

Comment: Do you mean you actually want to create variables based on the values? Java isn't a dynamic language, you can't just alter class definitions at runtime, if that's what you mean. Maybe you want a Map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple for loop can iterate over your array.

```
for(String elem : queryParams) {
    //do whatever with elem
}
```

Then if you want to use those values in another method of your program I'd suggest you pass your array to your method or just pass a single value (if you don't need every values) by calling your method like that : `aMethod(queryParams[*anIndex*]);` (in which case you wouldn't need to iterate on your array and assign to variable.

If you really want to assign your values to ids, maybe you could put them in a `map` in your for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use a simple for loop ?

```
    for(int i = 0; i<queryParams.length; i++) {
       // do something with queryParams[i]
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of the syntax for the for loop but curious about the syntax of storing each element in their rightful variables

Comment: But queryParams[i] is a rightful variable that you can use anywhere. What do you want to do with your "rightful" variable ?

Comment: I want to create a dynamic query that "or"s each element rather than just looking at the input string as one long statement.

Comment: @kevinsufferdini as G_H mentionned, Java isn't a dynamic language.